# In Chrome Browser on Android - Font Size that Responds to the Text Scaling option under Accessibility

Tags: javascript, fonts, scale

I see that some web sites clearly respond to the text scaling option found under Accessibility in the Chrome settings on Android.  I can't seem to find what that is though...I've tried rem, em, px on the html, body, div, etc.  Just looking to get some basic text to display in any element that will change size as I use the scaling option under accessibilty.
Thoughts?